# How to display a diagonal background image that is not a pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time with a diagonal background image. This is not a "pattern", but a full image used in two types of layouts. (Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg6xU.jpg)

1. On one template, the image should remain fixed on the page at 100%
   height, positioned to the top right and scrolls with the page.
2. On the second template, the image should maintain the same aspect
   ratio as it would in template one, but it should not be fixed.
   Instead, it should scroll up with the rest of the page.

I've been able to achieve the desired result for template one, but I'm having a hard time with template two.

Is Javascript the only solution here? If so, any recommendations? Again, the challenges I can't fix:

- Get the image to maintain the same aspect ratio as it would in template one (if it's 100% height to fit the window in template one, then it should size at 100% height in template two with the exception of being fixed) This is to maintain consistency between pages using separate templates.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: I have no code to reference for the actual challenge I'm facing. But here is the solution I've found for the first template:

CSS (applied to an img element):

```
.abovefold {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for the CSS `background-attachment` attribute. To fix a background, simply set it as such:

```
.example {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mcWseu1.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference#Background

I've demonstrated this in a fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/GHDbM/

When it comes to dimensioning the background, you'll want to set the `background-size` attribute:

```
.example {
    background-size: auto 100%; /* Adjust to element height */
}
```

The `auto` in the above example is for `width` and the `100%` is for height.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Another fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/sk2RY/

Comment: Good answer but I would avoid using w3schools as a reference, try http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference#Background or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: Ah, naturally. Thanks for the tip. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But I'm still running into issues getting the image to fit the height of the browser. Any recommendations?

Comment: Try setting `background-size: auto 100%;`. Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sk2RY/

Comment: Thanks. I've used that exact solution previously. The problem exists because the fixed version of the background image is meant to be used on a page that doesn't have below-the-fold content. The second template has page content below the fold, and the height of the body reflects that making the image larger.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Could you somehow illustrate this in your question?

Comment: Did you get this to work? Or can you elaborate on this fold layout?